# Can a web service client control number of parallel connections?

Tags: concurrency

Is there any way by which the client machine or application settings restrict the number of connections it can open to a web service? So i have a .net application that spawns multiple threads and each thread creates new instance of the proxy to the web service XXX. On each thread i am calling SomeXXX method using the instantiated proxy. So if the service allows 100 connections and i am creating 100 threads is there any reason i should not see 100 established connections when i do netstat?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
So the setting in machine config restricts internet connection (http/https outside your machine) to 2 by default. Modify the System.Net section of machine config and it works great

```
<connectionManagement>
<add address="*" maxconnection="12"/>
</connectionManagement>
```

Regards